# NetSuite Site Category Count

Tags: netsuite

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the NUMBER OF ITEMS in a category in netsuite?

I'm hoping for a getAttribute tag of some sort. I need the count of total items in order to create a pagination string url.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: I have a list of products in a category I would like to grab the number of items. NetSuite has default pagination for e-commerce but it wraps in a table and its hard to manipulate the css. 

I want to create the same category url using the range. (range=from,​to,​of) OF being the total category of items which i'm not sure how to get. 

For example http://www.wolfeelectronics.com/s.nl/sc.12/category.2/.f? range=11,13,13 would be the link 13 is the total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple method is to create a **saved search** with the criteria/filters you need.
You can create saved search either programmatically or by using the tools available in netsuite.
**The length of the result of saved search will show the total NUMBER OF ITEMS.**

NOTE : If you want, you can retrieve the entire details of each product from saved search results.